# Converting TStack code from Delphi to Lazarus

Tags: delphi, pascal, lazarus

In Delphi I have the following code, and all works well:

```
var
  StackOptions:TStack<String>;
  s:string;
  bfisio:boolean;
begin
  StackOptions:=TStack<String>.Create;
  //some pushs here 
  for s in StackOptions do begin
    dosomething;
  end;
end;
```

In Lazarus I can do this:

```
uses
  ..., gstack;

type
  TStringStack = specialize TStack<String>;

var
  StackOptions: TStringStack;
  s:string;
begin
  //But this code doesn;t compile
  StackOptions := TStringStack.Create;
  //some pushs here 
  for s in StackOptions do begin // <-- Error 
    dosomething;
  end;
end;
```

I get the next error in Lazarus:

> Compile Project, Target: TicketLaz.exe: Exit code 1, Errors: 1
>   umain.pas(263,12) Error: Cannot find an enumerator for the type "TStack$1$crcAC3AF268"

How could I loop the Stack and search for a value with Lazarus without removing items from Stack?

Comment: You've got the wrong data structure. If you want to search the entire container, you are looking for a list.

Comment: I am trying implement  a LIFO to undo changes done in a sequence of actions done in my app. I save a string in a Stack with the current state of my app and if the user cancel the action, I undo the changes.   In delphi, all works well using TStack. Then I was trying the same with Lazarus. Is better I do it with a List?

Comment: If you want to access the whole container then a stack seems wrong. I expect you can't iterate the gstack stack because it doesn't support iteration. I list will do.

Comment: I thought of using TStack because I have all code working in Delphi. I am doing a version to raspbian with FPC and I´d like to make only few changes  in my code. Thank you, Mr David

Comment: Just curious, why shouldn't you want / be able to iterate over a stack ?  For example, to determine whether or not something exists in the stack without having to pop everything out and then push everything back afterward (iterators are inspectors, not modifiers).  This seems like a reasonable thing to want or sometimes even need to do.  Which is presumably why other stack implementations provide enumerator/iterator support ?

Comment: FreePascal's `TStack` classes, both generic and non-generic variants, do not support any kind of enumeration at all, and that is exactly what the error message is saying ("*cannot find an enumerator*"). You can get the `Count`, but you cannot access individual items, only pop/peek the next item to be removed.  Whereas Delphi `TStack` classes support enumeration.

Comment: @Deltics If you can iterate over the entire container, then how is it different from TList?

Comment: @David - iterating over (passively inspecting) content is not *adding or *removing* content, and it is behaviour in **this** area that differentiates the different types of collections, not the ability to inspect the contents.

Comment: @Deltics You might ask why stacks exist at all is my point. Having fewer capabilities opens implementation opportunities.

Comment: @Daivd - you aren't making sense.  Stacks exist to provide specific LIFO behaviour *when adding and removing items* in a collection.  But passively inspecting items in a collection has no bearing on that behaviour.  Otherwise you have to *consume* in order to simply *inspect* which is not just unnecessary (and wrong) but downright dangerous.  Perhaps you should talk to the Java and .NET guys (not to mention the C++ containers guys) and tell them how they have got it wrong by not only allowing and supporting but actually *providing* iterators/enumerators over *their* stack collections ?

Comment: @David: A stack is LIFO, has methods like push, pop and peek and a List is random access. But I see no reason why a stack should not be iterable. You still don't have random access, so they are still quite different and serve different purposes.

Comment: @Rudy The STL stack, for example, is a container adapter. The underlying container may not support iteration. A class with fewer capabilities and constraints affords more opportunity for optimisation. I suspect that in the case of C++ the decision was taken with good reason.

Comment: That may be true for the STL. But the fact that the STL does not guarantee iteration does not mean that, generally, a stack can not be or should not be iterable. I find it quite useful if a stack, queue or list is iterable. Too bad for the STL that they don't.

Comment: FWIW, IME, adapters don't have much opportunities for optimization at all. They are pretty much depending on the class they wrap and must sometimes jump through hoops to get a desired result, if the underlying class does not easily support something.

Comment: @Deltics `std::stack<T>` does not support iteration.

Comment: @Rudy The adapter isn't necessarily where the optimisation would lie. The underlying container has that opportunity. I'd expect that the STL designers knew what they were doing.

Comment: Perhaps they knew what the were doing, perhaps not. I personally think the interface of the many containers in the STL is pretty inconsistent, except for the iterators and the existence of begin() and end() methods almost everywhere.

Comment: @David - std::stack<T> is a container adapter which may be created with a specified container<T>. i.e. std::stack may be iterated if you use an iteratable container as the backing store but not if you create a stack with a default deque container which isn't exposed and therefore isn't iterable.  This being the exception that proves the rule.  ;)

Comment: @Rudy You don't look at that an think, "hmm, what have I missed?"

Comment: @David: I don't follow, sorry.

Comment: @Rudy Well, the STL has a long history, originally conceived by Alexander Stepanov, and developed over 15 years before being accepted by the C++ standards committee. Many people, C++ experts, had opportunity to criticise and shape the design. You don't ever consider that with all these experts, so many people who clearly have far more experience, knowledge, and skills than you, that they might have taken decisions for reasons that you don't yet appreciate. Don't you ever doubt?

Comment: That may well be, and there are probably good reasons for why the STL is as it is, but I still don't like some of the decisions made, and I am not particulalry fond of the interface. Even committees and expert peer groups can make decisions I don't like. So this is not about doubt, it is about preference. And this still doesn't tell me why stacks should not be iterable.

Comment: @Rudy I explained why. Deltics explained why.

Comment: What the STL does with `std::stack<T>` is not an argument why a stack in Delphi or in other languages can not be iterable. This is Delphi (or FreePascal), not C++. IYWTPICPPTPICPP.

Comment: @Rudy open your mind

Comment: @David: my mind is open and that is why I can see that a stack can have iteration, and that not everything has to be like the STL.

Comment: @Rudy No it's not. You opened with "But I see no reason why a stack should not be iterable." That is a broad and general statement. Not limited to a specific compiler or library. We gave some examples of different design choices. Nobody said that everything has to be like the STL.

Comment: @David: Ok, then let's put it differently: I see good reasons for a stack to be iterable. You didn't. Anyway, do you know anyone who thinks that his or her mind are closed? I don't. Everyone thinks that their minds are open.

Comment: @Rudy I didn't say that I thought stacks should not be iterable. I said that some libraries had been designed that way for a specific reason. Different libraries are trying to address different goals. I don't think that stack containers should be iterable or not iterable. My point is that in different situations different choices are appropriate. You clearly have a narrower viewpoint believing that stacks should always be iterable.

Comment: Eventhe stacks in the STL are iterable, althiugh not directly. The underlying implementations, std::list, std::deque and std::vector are all iterable. So it seems std:.stack is just not iterable because the underlying containers already are. They decided not to build a stack of its own, just to make a wrapper. <shrug>

Comment: @David: my viewpoint is unimportant. Fact is that there are stacks that are iterable, and that there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis It's as if you don't read anything I ever write.

Comment: I don't read everything you ever write. <g>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FPC's stack is backed by a TVector.
The TVector has an enumerator.

You can easily add a class helper like so:
Quick and dirty code.

```
type
  TStringStack = specialize TStack<String>;

 type

   { TStackHelper }

   TVectorEnumerator = specialize TVector<string>.TVectorEnumerator;

   TStackHelper = class helper for TStringStack
     function GetEnumerator: TVectorEnumerator;
   end;

{ TStackHelper }

function TStackHelper.GetEnumerator: TVectorEnumerator;
begin
  Result:= FData.GetEnumerator;
end;
```

*I really don't see why a stack is not supposed to have an iterator.

Even in assembly you can simply do `mov reg,[esp-04]`.

This puritanical approach to data-structures helps no-one*

All this is complicated by the fact that TStack is generic.
I know FPC allows generic class helpers, but I'm not sure how to make the solution work for all `TStack<T>`

Another approach would be to simply edit `gstack.pas` to expose the iterator.

Comment: I doubt it is puritanical. I would expect that you can produce optimised implementations if you don't need to support iteration. I expect you'll find that in other languages where performance tends to be seen as more important, that this does happen.

Comment: Beside the STL, which languages omit iteration for performance reasons? Actually, I am not so sure that iteration was omitted from the STL stack for performance reasons.